# Unable to login to Skype Web SDK Samples

Tags: azure, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am trying to login to Skype for business Web SDK samples downloaded from [https://ucwa.skype.com](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313244)

I am running samples locally(http://localhost/) using IIS manager windows and getting bellow error messages.

**Cross domain Issue**
[image: Cross domain Issue]
**Auto Discovery failure**
[image: Auto Discovery failure]
**Browser Console Error**
[image: Console Error]

I have developer account in Office 365 and Azure AD account(30 days free trails account) with application created.

Kindly help me to resolve issue and help me to login to websdk samples.

**Edit :**

I have followed the blog from http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-run-the-new-skype-web-sdk-online-samples/,

In the end I got bellow errors:

Request

```
URL:https://webdirin1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 2):

The samples you are referencing, UCWA Helper Libraries, were not designed to support O365/Skype For Business Online accounts (only on-prem).  You would need to look at the following samples that use the Skype Web SDK to get support for Online accounts:

- [OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples)
- [Downloading and running the Skype Web SDK samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/downloadrunsamples)
- [Skype Web SDK Interactive Samples](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk)

There is no way to fix this issue with the UCWA Helper libraries without taking the time to integrate support for ADAL using something like [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js).

Answer (score 0):

Why is it linked with Azure? Is there a way to login to Skype for business Web SDK samples without Azure account?

Comment: The online account exists in Azure Active Directory as part of the an online deployment of Skype for Busines and this is also where permissions are controlled for what apps can access that information.  An on-premise user is not tied to Azure or Azure Active Directory and thus does not need these steps to use the Web SDK samples using an Azure account.

Answer (score 0):

If a developer is new to Skype for business Web SDK, refer the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal
This doc explains clear steps.

The application might be getting a token with its own credentials due to which the error comes up stating it is not registered for the account. Also, you may have to directly assign the application permissions.
Please double check if you have assigned the right permissions to the client application for accessing the Web application Interface.